# Subspace of $L^1(\Omega)$ closed

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{B}$ two sub-sigma-algebras and $f$ a $\mathcal{B}$-measurable function.
I want to show, that the subspace
$$\mathcal{L}:=\{\langle\phi,f\rangle : \phi\text{ measurable with respect to }\mathcal{A}\}\cap L^1{\Omega}$$
is a closed subspace of $L^1$.
Unfortunately I don't know how to start here. I'm thankful for every kind of help :)

Comment: What is $\langle \phi,f \rangle$? Perhaps the conditional expectation of $f$ with respect to $\phi$?

Comment: Oh sorry. I forgot to mention that $f$ and $\phi$ are vector-valued functions and $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ the euclidean scalar product.

Comment: Then if you proceed by components, it is the same to consider $\phi,f$ scalar-valued and $\{ \phi f \} \cap L^1$.

Comment: That said, here's an idea for a partial solution. If $|f|$ is bounded below by a nonzero constant then $\phi f$ is uniquely determined by $\phi$ and vice versa, so if you have a sequence in $\mathcal{L}$ that converges in $L^1$ then it can be written as $\phi_n f$ in a unique way. Then argue that in this case the only way to have $\phi_n f \to \phi f$ is if you in fact have $\phi_n \to \phi$ and then you can just used closedness of $L^1$ itself. How can you proceed without this additional constraint?

Comment: I don't understand why I can proceed by components since I have $\Vert \langle \phi,f\rangle\Vert_{L^1}=\int_\Omega \vert\sum_{i=1}^n\phi_i(\omega)f_i(\omega)\vert\mathbb{P}(\omega)$ and not $\Vert \langle \phi,f\rangle\Vert_{L^1}=\int_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^n\vert\phi_i(\omega)f_i(\omega)\vert\mathbb{P}(\omega)$.

Comment: Because of the triangle inequality: if $|\phi_i f_i|$ are all $L^1$ then so is $\langle \phi,f \rangle$.

Comment: Yes, that is clear but the reverse implication doesn't hold I think...and thats what I need.

Comment: Under the assumption that $f$ doesn't vanish that's not actually a problem, I think, but this does seem like a rather technical problem when $f$ can vanish.